# Windows 11 Pro: Hide the taskbar, bottom horizontal bar

Tags: windows, taskbar, windows-11

I just got the new Windows 11 Pro. I have "Automatically Hide the Taskbar" in settings, however, after saving the settings, the taskbar horizontal bar is till showing below. How can I remove it?

[image]

Comment: What vertical bar?   Does the task bar on the bottom hide?

Comment: hi @John apologies, should be horizontal bar

Comment: If your machine came preloaded with Windows 11 and the task bar does not hide even though set to hide, then contact Manufacturer’s Support (assuming an OEM license).

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: hi @mashuptwice yes